# What are the rules for dynamic dispatching in c++?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I wonder how dynamic dispatching really works in C++. To illustrate my question, I will start by some Java code.

```
class A
{
  public void op(int x, double y) { System.out.println("a"); }
  public void op(double x, double y) { System.out.println("b"); }
}

class B extends A
{
  public void op(int x, double y) { System.out.println("c"); }
  public void op(int x, int y) { System.out.println("d"); }
}

class C extends B
{
  public void op(int x, int y) { System.out.println("e"); }
}

public class Pol
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    A a = new C();
    B b = new C();

    /* 1 */ a.op(2, 4);
    /* 2 */ b.op(2.0, 4.0);
  }
}
```

The call `a.op(2, 4)` will print "c", since indeed the compiler:

- looks into Class `A` (since `a` is declared to be a variable of type `A`) which method is the closest to `op(int, int)`,
- can't find a `op(int, int)` method but finds the method `op(int, double)` (with a single auto-cast `int` -> `double`),
- then fixes this signature.

During the execution, the JVM:

- looks for a method with the signature `op(int, double)` fixed by the compiler into Class `C` but doesn't find it,
- looks inside C's super-class, i.e., `B`,
- and finally finds a method `op(int, double)`, then calls it.

The same principle applies to the call `b.op(2.0, 4.0)`, which prints "b".

Now, consider the equivalent code in C++

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
  virtual void op(int x, double y) { std::cout << "a" << std::endl; }
  virtual void op(double x, double y) { std::cout << "b" << std::endl; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  void op(int x, double y) { std::cout << "c" << std::endl; }
  virtual void op(int x, int y) { std::cout << "d" << std::endl; }
};

class C : public B
{
public:
  void op(int x, int y) { std::cout << "e" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  A *a = new C;
  B *b = new C;

  /* 1 */ a->op(2,  4);
  /* 2 */ b->op(2.0, 4.0);

  delete a;
  delete b;
}
```

`a->op(2, 4)` will print "c", like Java. But `b->op(2.0, 4.0)` outputs "c" again, and there, I'm lost.

What are exactly the rules applied at the compilation and during the execution in C++ for dynamic dispatching?
(Notice you will have the same behavior from the C++ code if you write `virtual` in front of each function; it changes nothing here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For C++, when you do `b->op(2.0, 4.0);` the compiler looks in `B`, finds a method it can call `(int x, double y)` and uses it. It does not look in the superclass if any method in the subclass can handle the call. This is called method hiding, ie. `op(double, double)` is hidden.

If you want to make it select the `(double x, double y)` version, you need to make the function visible inside of `B` with the following declaration inside `B`:

```
using A::op;
```

[Further explanation of the rules](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/hiding-rule.html)

Comment: We're talking about "base classes" in C++ - not "super classes".

Comment: Still, I'm confused. I understand now the method hiding principle, but with `b->op(2.0, 4.0)` we are asking for a function with two floating numbers as arguments. How come the compiler can think it is a good idea to choose a function with the signature `op(int, double)`? It can't (shouldn't?) auto-cast from `double` toward `int`; there is a chance of loss of precision.

Comment: @FlorianRichoux `double` is implicitly convertible to `int` and `void (int, double)` is a better match than `void (int, int)`. The `void (double, double)` in `A` is never seen because name lookup ends once it's found `op` in `B`.

Comment: @FlorianRichoux If `B` didn't define `op` then name lookup wouldn't find it in `B` so it would then look it up in the base class. This happens in any kind of scope; classes aren't special in this way. Take the example of a global function `foo` and a function in your namespace called `foo`; if you call `foo` it finds the function in your namespace and then stops, never finding the global `foo` (disregarding ADL).

Comment: @FlorianRichoux The implicit conversion rules in C++ are a lot looser than in Java. Possible loss of precision won't stop the compiler from doing it; it just might lead it to emit a warning with the right flags.

Answer (score 1):

By declaring a new overload to `op` in `B` you have hidden the base versions. The compiler will only dispatch based on 'B' which is why it selects `op(int,double)`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will warn/error on conversions if you tell it to. Using gcc, the compiler arguments `-Wconversion -Werror` will prevent your code from compiling, as you are right, there is a potential loss in precision here.

Given that you didn't turn on this compiler option, the compiler is happy to resolve your call to b->op(double, double) to B::op(int, double).

Please keep in mind that this is a compile time decision - not a runtime/polymorphic decision.

The actual vtable of the "b" pointer will have a method op(int, int) available at runtime, but the compiler doesn't know about this method at compile time. It only can assume that the b pointer is of type B*.

Answer (score 0):

You start with the polymorphic behavior in your base class `A`. Then, using the same signature, you cannot stop this in the derived classes.

It's not necessary, if you declare the same method `virtual` or not.

**You have to change the signature!**

Furthermore, you have the visibility problem. This line

```
B *b = new C;
b->op(2.0, 4.0);
```

The compiler looks for a method within your class `B`. The `op`-methods hide the methods with the same name of class `A` (overload resolution). If he founds something useful, he is just using it.